# Amazon Search API

Tags: python, ruby, web-services, amazon-product-api

Is there a good way to access amazon search results (given a query) in Ruby or Python? I've been looking around for APIs and found a Product Advertising API which seems to not be the same as search.

I would prefer not to have to scrape the amazon search web-page given a query (embedded in a url).

Answer (score 5):

I have been working with Amazon API for several years and I will admit that they seem to try to hide what they are doing with their regular affiliate stuff, like Amazon Search, as if they don't want you to use the API or at least make it difficult.

So, in your affiliate dashboard, click the 'Product API' tab at the top.

Next, you will need to create your public and private keys. If those aren't created and set up, you won't be able to access the API. Also be aware that even though Amazon does have a RESTful API, it requires a callback, regardless of the language you use. (Unless you're going to use SOAP) Once those are created, it should open up some new options for you in you affiliate dashboard.

Finally, Amazon has code samples out the wazoo, but I cannot testify that either the Ruby or Python ones are any good (as I have done mine with cURL and php), but it should give you a good starting point anyway. Go here: http://aws.amazon.com/code/Product%20Advertising%20API?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1

I do see python and ruby listed here in the code samples and docs. Be aware Amazon likes to change things frequently, sometimes without notice. But I did just notice while doing this a section about a new node js library for AWS...sweet. Amazon for all it bs does do a good job.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [Product Advertising API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/CHAP_Intro_AAWS.html)

From the documentation, it will allow you to provide results, allow shopping, and complete purchases through Amazon:

1. > Your application uses the Product Advertising API to supply item
   >   descriptions and images, and customer and seller reviews, which you
   >   present to your customers.
2. > Customers shop on your web site.
3. > When the customer is ready to purchase the items in their e-commerce
   >   shopping cart, your application sends an HTML form to Product
   >   Advertising API and Amazon completes the purchase by getting purchase
   >   information, such as payment method and shipping address, and then
   >   Amazon fulfills the order by shipping the items.

So if you are only trying to show search results, then [these search options](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/SearchOperations.html) will fit your needs.